wildfly maven plugin system properties in cli scripts
I use the wildfly-maven-plugin to package my application with a wildfly. I have some cli scripts that I want to run in order to for example add oracle driver and datasource. I would like to use system properties to pass to my cli scripts and I have tried reading the documentation (which is minimal and requires a lot of trial and error) without succeeding.
I have tried following the last example here https://docs.wildfly.org/wildfly-maven-plugin/releases/4.2/execute-commands-example.html.
My pom.xml:
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>package</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <bootable-jar>true</bootable-jar>
                    <bootable-jar-name>application-job-bootable.jar</bootable-jar-name>
                    <feature-packs>
                        <feature-pack>
                            <location>wildfly@maven(org.jboss.universe:community-universe)#22.0.1.Final</location>
                        </feature-pack>
                    </feature-packs>
                    <commands>
                        <!-- Set the system property in the server configuration -->
                        <command>/system-property=foo:add(value=bar)</command>
                    </commands>
                    <system-properties>
                        <test.ip>TEST</test.ip>
                        <bing.test>TEST2</bing.test>
                    </system-properties>
                    <packaging-scripts>
                        <packaging-script>
                            <scripts>
                                <script>scripts/wf-ports.cli</script>
                                <script>scripts/add-user.cli</script>
                                <script>scripts/add-driver.cli</script>
                                <script>scripts/add-datasource-node.cli</script>
                            </scripts>
                        </packaging-script>
                    </packaging-scripts>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

The documentation shows nothing of how to reference these system props but when running the /system-property=*:read-resource from one of my cli-scripts it returns an empty result. So neither specifying  or using the  works.

I am not sure what you are asking about. The result of system-property=*:read-resource is empty because there are no system properties defined in the default server profile. For CLI reference what you can configure with CLI, refer to this page: https://docs.wildfly.org/34/wildscribe/

Also, the correct reference for the version of the plugin you are using is here: https://docs.wildfly.org/wildfly-maven-plugin/releases/5.0/package-mojo.html

The package goal will not execute the commands defined in <commands/>. That configuration parameter is not defined for the package goal. You can, however, run the commands in your packaging-scripts definition https://docs.wildfly.org/wildfly-maven-plugin/releases/5.0/package-mojo.html#packagingScripts.

@Rado
See comment below on your answer. Where did you put the file?

Here's an example how to pass properties to the packaging scripts from the properties file:
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
               ...
                    <packaging-scripts>
                        <packaging-script>
                            <commands>
                                <command>/socket-binding-group=standard-sockets/socket-binding=jgroups-udp:write-attribute(name=port,value=${PORT})</command>
                            </commands>
                            <properties-files>
                                <property-file>jgroups.properties</property-file>
                            </properties-files>
                            <resolve-expressions>true</resolve-expressions>
                        </packaging-script>
                    </packaging-scripts>

and the content of the jgroups.properties file is e.g.
PORT=35200

This resolves the expression in the CLI command and not at the runtime.
Refer to plugin documentation at https://docs.wildfly.org/wildfly-maven-plugin/releases/5.0/package-mojo.html#packagingScripts

The properties-files solution didn't work for me. Maybe I am doing it wrong but i created a properties file in the root of my module with the same contents as yours. I had the exact same command as you but the build fails:
/socket-binding-group=standard-sockets/socket-binding=jgroups-udp:write-attribute(name=port,value=${PORT}) {     "outcome" => "failed",     "failure-description" => "WFLYCTL0216: Management resource '[     (\"socket-binding-group\" => \"standard-sockets\"),     (\"socket-binding\" => \"jgroups-udp\") ]' not found",     "rolled-back" => true
